# Populating a listbox

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to figure out how the http://www.bitinstant.com page is made, especially how the listbox on the right is populated... and am a bit confused.

I know the listbox's name is "dest_exchange" but can't figure out where the data is coming from to populate the box.

Can you have a look and tell me where is the source URL/data please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, there's an event attached to the `onchange()` of select box: `GetQuote();`. And the function is defined in the same page:

```
function GetQuote() {
      var $method   = $('#pay_method').val();
      var $amount   = $('#amount').val();
      var $exchange = $('#dest_exchange').val();
      if ($method == "zipzap" || $method == 'fuze') {
        $("#ofacbox").show();
      } else {
        $("#ofacbox").hide();
      }
      get_destaccount_tooltip($exchange);
      $("#destaccount_label").html(get_destaccount_tooltip($exchange));
      $("#payfromimg").attr("src","/static/images/logos/"+$method+"_carosel.png");
      $("#paytoimg").attr("src","/static/images/logos/"+$exchange+"_carosel.png");
      verifyMtGox();
      if($amount.length==0) { return; }
```

Can't post the full code here, but it is from line 72 of the source of the page.

Comment: I saw that, but still cannot find where the data is coming from...

Comment: Dude, what data you need?

Comment: Where it says "bitcoin to email"

Comment: It is just hiding the field `MtGox Account`. That's all. And which data?

Comment: Click on the listbox, and one of the options are "Bitcoin to email", I want to know where that text is coming from as I cannot find it anywhere in the "view source" so it must be coming from an external source... where?

Comment: Okay, @Ryan it comes from: https://www.bitinstant.com/start_tx